# Standard error and distribution of derived regression coefficients

Tags: regression, standard-error, inference

I completed this simple regression: Y = (1-1/a) X1 + (b/a) X2

I am however interested in inference on a and b. How do I convert standard errors and distribution of (1-1/a) and (b/a), to those of a and b ?

Surely the estimators a, b will not at all be asymptotically normal distributed because for example b = (b/a)*a the product of two random variables?

Comment: Did you include an intercept?

Comment: Included intercept, found to be insignificant. Estimated again without the intercept. Hence no I did not include intercept.